# grouping launch file

Tags: roslaunch, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I need to start different nodes in the launch file.
At the moment I do it by defining 2 arguments (`var1` and `var2`) and then by grouping the launch files. Something like:

```
<group if="$(arg var1)"> 
   start some nodes
</group>

<group if="$(arg var2)">
  start  other nodes
</group>
```

and launching from terminal the following:

```
roslaunch my_package my_launch_file var1:=true var2:=false
```

This works, but my question is: is there a way I could launch by defining only one arg?
For example what I want to achieve is:

```
<arg name="variable"/> 
    
    <group if=**(variable=1)**>        --> How can I implement this?
    start some nodes
        </group>
        
        <group if=(variable=2)>
start other nodes
        </group>
```

and therefore using from terminal only:

```
roslaunch my_package launch_file variable:=1
```

or

```
roslaunch my_package launch_file variable:=2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376054/grouping-launch-file/) by [LR1997](https://answers.ros.org/users/72501/lr1997/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2021-04-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use `if` along with the `$(eval <expression>)` substitution as described in the [`roslaunch` XML wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML).

> $(eval ) allows to evaluate arbitrary complex python expressions.

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2021-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LR1997](https://answers.ros.org/users/72501/lr1997/) on 2021-04-14**:
Thank you, this solved my problem :)